# How to union two rows in one by connecting it on some cell in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

My query:

```
-
```

I have 2 results of my query:

```
SA01 |  False   | SA01  |   False | No |    Yes |   [NULL] |    VA - HRD 1
SA01 |  False   | SA01  |   False | No |    Yes |   [NULL] |    VA - NOVA 1
```

I want to union them into one row and different cell values should union into one like this:

```
SA01  | False  |SA01  | False  |No  |Yes  | [NULL]  |   VA - HRD 1, VA - NOVA 1
```

Is it possible in SQL?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing your table structures

Comment: Post your table structure and database version too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use[listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).

```
select
  a, b, c, listagg(col_with_VA_Values, ', ') within group (order by ...)
from
  table
group by
  a, b, c;
```

As already was pointed out, without table definition (`create table...`) and example data (`insert into .... values (...)`) you can only expect a quite vague answer.

Comment: Thanks, I can't write table structure because it's too big, but I write my query, maybe you'll understand something by watching on it...

Comment: @HughJones changed `','` to `', '`.